# How can I determine type of object pointer points to?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

Im playing with my smart pointer class and I want to implement ++ and -- operators with the following behavior: If pointer points to single variable or if it points to array and ++(--) moves pointer out of array bounds an exception should be thrown when trying to ++(--).

Something like that:

```
class A;

SmartPtr<A> s(new A[3]);
SmartPtr<A> s1(new A());
++s;//ok
--s;//ok
--s;//exception OutOfBounds thrown
++s1;//exception OutOfBounds thrown
--s1;//exception OutOfBounds thrown
```

I tried to use typeid. But it returns A type anyway.

```
A* arr=new A[3];
typeid(arr).name();//type is P1A
typeid(--arr).name();//type is P1A
typeid(arr+7).name();//type is P1A
```

So is there any way to determine does pointer point to "my" type of object after ++(--)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new A[3]` returns an `A*`, just like `new A` does.  So you can't distinguish them.

If you want your class to do bounds checking, then you will need to explicitly tell it how many items are in the array.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you want to implement this kind of behaviour, you must store somewhere the size of the allocated array.

Comment: Ok, but how can i pass array size to my constructor then? How can i get "3" from SmartPtr<A> s(new A[3]);?

Comment: @Alexander You cannot ask or query A in any way, so you must for example pass the size as the second parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this kind of bounds checking if you use a utility function, rather than array `new` directly, e.g.:

```
template <class Type, std::size_t size>
SmartPtr<Type> MakeArrayPtr()
{
  return SmartPtr<Type>(new Type[size], size);
}
```

If the smart pointer deletes the object, remember to have it use `delete[]` in the case of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

stop using raw pointers/raw arrays and start using a vector. Then you can get the size of the vector and simply store the position of the element in your smart pointer class.